# Global variables in complex Tcl/Tk apps? Design patterns, conventions, style?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Whenever I write a Tcl/Tk app, I am plagued by the necessity to use global variables because callback scripts are evaluated in the top level scope, and I always want to use proc's for callbacks to hide the complexity. But I hate having globals in all my procedures...

My way around this is to use a parameter for the name of a global variable and upvar to reference it, so at least I can see which global variable is being used (and modified) as part of the proc call.  Often that is a single STATE array.

It seems that my applications are always in the style of a list of buttons in the main window that fire off toplevels that perform the actual work, querying databases, storing and modify results, etc.

I am tempted to use a different namespace for each toplevel so that sub-widgets can reference variables in this namespace without clobbering true globals, but I am not sure if that is a good idea.

What do other Tcl/Tk programmers do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many applications are simple enough that just using global variables works quite acceptably.

However, where you need something more sophisticated, the first thing to try is probably to make the global variables be arrays that are indexed by the name of the toplevel widget for the dialog. Getting the identity of the toplevel is usually pretty easy; you can either just store it in the binding/callback (the `list` command is useful for getting quoting right), or you can use `[winfo toplevel %W]` in a binding.

```
proc makeDialog {w} {
    global dialogState
    toplevel $w
    button $w.btn -text "Foo Bar!" -command [list dialogCallback $w]
    bind $w <Escape> {cancelDialog %W}
    set dialogState($w) 123
    # Etc with making the dialog pretty...
}
proc dialogCallback {w} {
    global dialogState
    incr dialogState($w)
}
proc cancelDialog {someWidgetWithTheFocus} {
    global dialogState
    set w [winfo toplevel $someWidgetWithTheFocus]
    puts "state = $dialogState($w)"
    destroy $w
}
```

(I put the `winfo toplevel` inside the callback as it is a good idea to keep binding scripts themselves as simple as possible.)

You can easily use a namespaced variable too for this. The global namespace is not *that* special, but good Tcl programmers usually consider it to be the property of Tcl itself and the application; library packages are encouraged to use other namespaces. (Variations on using an array are possible, such as a dictionary from 8.5 onwards.)

It's also possible to use an object system (the ones that are generally recommended these days are TclOO, incr Tcl, XOTcl and Snit). Ask another question if you want advice focussed on one of them.

Comment: Thanks Donal, you are helpful as always -- indexing with the toplevel is a great idea, and might do all I need.  The 'namespace code' approach looks interesting too, though a little obscure.  Re OO approaches, is there a tutorial for this kind of use case?

Answer (score 1):

As you have suggested, you can use namespaces to segregate the procedures and variables for different parts of you application. The command that you will be interested in is `namespace code`. The `namespace code` command "captures the current namespace context" and makes namespaces useful for containing callbacks. For small to medium sized applications, namespace techniques work reasonably well for me.